# Spring MVC modelAndView object in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, controller

Problem:
I have a simple controller which returns me a list of hardcoded locations. When i want to get my locations in my javascript file using $.get and print it in my console, i get some weird "undefined" results.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/locationOverview")
public class LocationOverviewController {

    private LocationGuide service;

    public LocationOverviewController() {
        this.service = new LocationGuide("Memory");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)    
    protected ModelAndView getLocations() {
        ArrayList<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
        locations.add(new Location(1,"KHL",new Geolocation(51,51)));
        locations.add(new Location(2,"KUL",new Geolocation(51,51)));

        return new ModelAndView("locationOverview", "locations", locations);
    }

}
```

mapScript JS:

```
function initialize() {
    $.get("locationOverview.htm", function(data){
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            console.log(data[i].name);
        }
    })
}
```

JSP file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="domain.Location"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Leuven Speaks</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/mapScript.js" />"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">

        <jsp:include page="header.jspf"/>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: `i get some weird "undefined" results` what is it?

Comment: Is the 2nd agrument of [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is missing?

Comment: this is what i get in my console: http://i.imgur.com/HB1hki8.png

Answer (score 0):

You should actually inspect with dev tools what that data contains. The controller method you show us looks like it is not the one mapped to `locationOverview.htm`. If you want to query data with ajax, return the list using the @ResponseBody annotation instead.

Data passed in a model would be available in the JSP page that you define as the view in ModelAndView.

Some learning resources:

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/json-response-with-responsebody_31.html

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging